# NAS share not accessible using a CNAME from Windows 2008 R2

Tags: networking, cname-record, share

I have a NAS filer share say \xyz.abc.def.com. I am trying to access the share from Windows server 2008R2 Server.

We have a CNAME xyz.def.com pointing to xyz.abc.def.com.

I am able to access the share using \xyz.abc.def.com as well as the IP but unable to access the share using \xyz.def.com

a) DisableStrictNameChecking is 1 on Windows Server 2008R2
b) NetBios over TCP is default. I tried setting it to Enabled but no luck

I get the error 0x80004005, unspecified error

Comment: `DisableStrictNameChecking` would be for accessing a share `ON` the Windows Server 2008 R2 server, not for accessing a share `FROM` the server.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty but I wanted people to refrain from this answers. Could you please suggest what could be the issue here?

Comment: I don't understand what `I wanted people to refrain from this answers` means. Did you not want any answers to your question?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Nope. I want people not to give me answers like disabling Strict name checking as this is already checked. And you are right about it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the basics and verified that DNS is resolving the CNAME properly? Use nslookup from the machine in question (to ensure that it can resolve the address, as knowing a different system can resolve it would not be helpful) and lookup the records.

Comment: Yes. It resolves to the correct IP. Checked with Nslookup as well. No issues found in CNAME resolution. I had also tried updating the Hosts file to check if there was any issues with Name resolution but that did not help